# What happens to our Philosophies if "Karma" is rejected?

Tags: philosophy, karma, advaita, vishishtadvaita, sankhya

What Happens to our philosophy if the concept of "Karma" is rejected?

What will be its effect on ADvaita, Visistadvaita, Dvaita, Bheda-Abheda?

What will be its effect on Nyaya, Yoga, Sankhya?

Are there any thought experiments done in past to quantify the need of "Theory of Karma" in establishing any of the philosophies?

Comment: All modern day Hindus are followers of Vyasa. They all share 3 commonalities. Belief in the Vedas as the word of God, belief in God, and belief in cycles and karma. To not assert karma is to be hetrodox, a non Hindu. Your question is asking for opinions.

Comment: There are more than millions of people who are Hindus but who don't know what is to be "followers of Vyasa". Don't force your narrow minded definition of Hinduism on every Hindus. Never going to work.@SwamiVishwananda

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda In your case then no questions can be asked as scriptures are variety and many schools of thoughts also there in scriptures which as per you will be opnioon based when author asks reference from scripture.  Please have a look on what's asked twice thrice before closing.

Comment: Reincarnation implies karma. Otherwise, how is the soul meaningfully the same thing it was in the previous body?